# return daily rows for a range of dates

Tags: ms-access, vba

MS Access 2003.

I need to get the array of dates which are located in the range *start_date* to *end_date*.
I not found such function in standard set of MS Access.

I write VBA function:

```
Option Compare Database
' © Andrey Bushman, 2014
' Get the array of dates which are located in the range start_date to end_date.
' The result is an array of Date items.
Public Function GetDays(start_date As Date, end_date As Date)

If start_date > end_date Then
 ' end_date can't be less than start_date.
 GetDays = Null
 Exit Function
End If

Dim size As Long
size = end_date - start_date

Dim result() As Date
ReDim result(size)  ' including the range boundaries.

Dim index As Long
index = 0

Dim day As Date
day = start_date

Do While day <= end_date
    result(index) = day
    day = day + 1
    index = index + 1
Loop

    GetDays = result
End Function
```

My SQL query:

```
SELECT tbChecks.CheckId, tbChecks.[In], tbChecks.Back, GetDays([In],[Back]) AS DayItem FROM tbChecks;
```

But I get an *#Error* text in the *DayItem* field for each record.

This is not work too:

```
SELECT GetDays(CDate("01.01.2014"), CDate("05.01.2014")) as DayItem;
```

I get the error: *Data type mismatch in criteria expression. (Error 3464)*.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to get a one-column result set with a row for each date between start_date and end_date (inclusive)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting errors because your VBA function is returning an array of `Date` values but the Access Database Engine does not have an `Array` field type. Even if it did, you would wind up with a single row containing an array of dates and (according to the comments to the question) you want each date in a separate row.

You should be able to accomplish your goal without using VBA at all if you create a "Numbers" table with sequential integer values from 0 to a sufficiently large value, e.g.,

```
   n
----
   0
   1
   2
   3
...
 998
 999
1000
```

and then use a query like this:

```sql
SELECT DateAdd("d",n,#2014-01-01#) AS DayItem 
FROM Numbers 
WHERE n <= DateDiff("d",#2014-01-01#,#2014-01-05#)
```

returning

```
   DayItem
----------
2014-01-01
2014-01-02
2014-01-03
2014-01-04
2014-01-05
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I create the "Numbers" table through the SQL single query, instead of manually?

Comment: @Bush Unfortunately, no, because Access SQL does not support Common Table Expressions (CTEs). The [Numbers] table has to be a "real" table. You could write a little VBA routine to write the rows into it, or you could create the rows in Excel and then import them into Access. There's no great harm in the [Numbers] table having more rows than necessary, so just make it big enough to safely cover the expected range of values needed.